# Blinky Led not Blinking

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gpio, windows-10-iot-core

Could not get the led light to blink after following this tutorial (the app graphical interface blinks):

[a simple LED blinking app and connect a LED to your Windows 10 IoT Core device.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Docs/GetStarted/rpi3/sdcard/stable/getstartedstep4)

Here is an image of the current setup:
[image]

**Yellow to GPIO 5 - Pin29**

**Red to Pin17 - 3.3V**

In the Tutorial, the breadboard shorter leg appears to be the one connected to the power and not the long leg as written in the instructions

Comment: Not sure this belongs on SO.

Comment: @DarrenYoung, where do you suggest?

Comment: Probably https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ since this question seems to be more about connecting electrical components.  There's also https://iot.stackexchange.com/ but that's more on the software configuration and setup side of things.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the red wire from Pin17 to Pin1, and even though both of them are marked as 3.3V, Pin17 for some wicked reason is not a good fit for this circuit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible if you connect wires right, you can try to have a test，connect 3.3V pin to longer leg and connect GND to shorter leg.If it not works that must be your LED problem

Comment: Moving the red wire to Pin1 solved the problem as seen in the proposed answer. What I could not explain is why Pin17 did not work for that purpose?

Comment: @usefulBee  Pin1 and Pin17 is same DC Power, It could be your board problem